# Program in python to generate a random integer from 1 to 16 with a single six-sided die

Tags: python

I am writing a program in Python where you generate a random integer from 1 to 16 inclusive where your only random number generator is a six-sided die. Assuming a function named `roll6` which returns a 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6, and then writing a function named `roll16` which returns an integer between 1 and 16 inclusive.
I wrote the below code that generates the random integer using 3 dices but stuck on doing the same with a single dice:

```
import random

# Roll6 function to return random number between 1 and 6
def roll6():
    return(random.randint(1,6))

# Roll16 function to call Roll6 function thrice while re 
# rolling the dice when total is over 16
# Our range with 3 dices are 3 - 18, so I am deducting 2 to set the range from 1 to 16
def roll16():
    value = (roll6() + roll6() + roll6()) - 2
    return value

# Print the random value returned by roll16
i = roll16()
while i != 1:
    print(i)
    i = roll16()
print(I)
```

Any idea on how to do this with a single dice? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do it with "single dice". I mean... it can be a single dice which you roll multiple times, but then one solution is exactly this. BUT: if you were meant to make a uniform random (all have chance of being 1/16), then "single dice" is actually a huge hint

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by: `generates the random integer using 3 dices but stuck on doing the same with a single dice`? Seems like there is no difference logically between rolling one dice three times or three dice one time, especially with the pseudo-random numbers coming from the `random` library.

Comment: ... "roll" the same die 3 times. I believe what you have is sufficient, is it not?

Comment: Wouldn't `random.randint(1,16)` produce a single dice throw?

Comment: @Derek you must've missed the part where it was a single six-sided die.

Comment: Roll the die once to determine if the answer is from 1-8 or from 9-16 (e.g. 1,2,3 means 1-8, and 4,5,6 means 9-16). Do that same binary search type thing to divide those 8 choices down to 4, then to 2, then to 1.

Comment: E.g. I roll 4 and so have 9-16. I roll 1 and so have 9-12. I roll 2 and so have 9-10. I roll 5 and so have 10. This method is even a uniform distribution

Comment: Your problem states 'stuck on doing the same with a single dice'. Are you trying to get a result 1 to16 from a single 6 sided dice??:)

Comment: You can't get all numbers in [1,16] with a single sided dice unless you roll it multiple times, which is what you're already doing.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments you cannot generate 16 values from 6 values, however you can use your generator twice to produce.

Your method you used inneficient in the sense that you use loose entropy (randomness), each dice roll gives you `log2(6) = 2.58` bit.

And the output is not as random as it could be. Your procedure will draw numbers from 1 to 16 in a non uniform distribution, here I give you the plot of the probabilities of each value.
[image]

This distribution gives you `3.6` bit of entropy (the efficiency is `3.6/7.75` bit per bit).

Also the resulting uniform distribution of the numbers from 1 to 16 would have `4` bit of entropy (i.e. it is more random). If you wanted to generate many bits you could use almost all the randomness from the dices. For the 4-bit we need to roll the dice at least twice and this will give `4/5.17` bit per bit.

Basically you extract 2 bit from each roll then you have the best you can achieve something like this.

```
def roll4():
     while True:
         p = roll6()
         if p <= 4:
             return p;
def roll16():
    value = (roll4() - 1) * 4 + roll4();
    return value
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to simulate the probability distribution of three dice rolls in a single randomized event.
One can calculate the probability of each roll outcome analytically, for example three ones is 1/(6^3), two ones and a two is 3 / (6^3), etc... or just use the Table 2 for `k=3` from [this paper](https://digitalscholarship.unlv.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1025&context=grrj). Once you have that probability distribution, you can just look at its cumulative distribution and then sample based on a random number between 0 and 1.

```
import numpy as np

# p is the number of ways one can get the roll, so p[0] says there is
# one way to get "1", p[1] says there are three ways to get "2", etc.
p = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 25, 27, 27, 25, 21, 15, 10, 6, 3, 1]
P = np.cumsum(p)/sum(p)

def roll(N):
    x = np.random.random(N)
    y = [np.argmax(value < P) + 1 for value in x]
    return(y)
```

Comparing to expectations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 10**6
plt.hist(roll(N), np.arange(0.5,17.5), density = True, label = 'Monte Carlo')
plt.plot(np.arange(1,17), p / np.sum(p), 'o', label = 'Theory')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Probability density')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rollling 16 from a single dice can be done in multiple way.

1. Rerolling of individual dice is not allowed and event of rolling 3 dice needs to repeated.
2. Rerolling of individual dice is allowed and can be used to replace outcome of one of 3 dice rolled previously.

When rerolling of individual dice is not allowed.

```py
import random

# Roll6 function to return random number between 1 and 6
def roll6():
    return(random.randint(1,6))

# Roll16 function to call Roll6 function thrice while re 
# rolling the dice when total is over 16
# Our range with 3 dices are 3 - 18, so I am deducting 2 to set the range from 1 to 16
def roll16():
    value = (roll6() + roll6() + roll6()) 
    if value <= 16:
        return value
    elif value > 16 
        return roll16()
    else:
        print('didnt expect this value') 
# Print the random value returned by roll16

# this part of your code is going inside a infinite loop
i = roll16()
while i != 1:
    print(i)
    i = roll16()
```

Rerolling of individual dice is allowed and can be used to replace outcome of one of 3 dice rolled previously.

In this you will try to replace the dice with maximum value with new roll and check if its greater than 16.

```py
def roll16():
    rolls = [roll6(), roll6(), roll6()]
    while sum(rolls)>16:
        roll = roll6()
        max_idx = rolls.index(max(rolls))
        rolls[max_idx] = roll
    return sum(rolls)
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically there wouldn't really be any difference. Did you mean something like this?

```
def roll16():
    i = 0
    sum = -2
    while i < 3:
        sum += roll6()
        i += 1
    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can roll once and get numbers from 1 to 6, and than interpret each number as a chance to get number from other range ) so if u get 1 it can ganarate random(1,3), 2 is for random(3,6), 3 - for random(6,9) and so on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

While, in a fair die, all the 6 sides have equal probability (i.e. it is a uniform distribution), as described above, those experiments will give different probabilities in the 1-16 case.
A way to avoid this **could** be the following:

- throwing a die twice has 36 possible ordered outcomes: 1 & 1, 1 & 2, ... 6 & 5, 6 & 6.
- if i1 is the result of the first toss and i2 of the second, we could map the outcomes to 18 numbers: 1 & 1 -> 1, 1 & 2 -> 1, 1 & 3 -> 2, 1 & 4 -> 2, 1 & 5 -> 3 ... 6 & 4 -> 17, 6 & 5 -> 18, 6 & 6 -> 18
- This mapping is obtained using: *3 * i1 - 2 + int((i2-1)/2)*
- If the outcomes are 17 or 18, the experiment is repeated.

The following piece of code will allow to obtain a random number between 1 & 16 from a uniform distribution

```
import random
from collections import Counter

def roll6():
   return random.randint(1, 6)

def __throw_dice__():
   i1 = roll6()
   i2 = roll6()
   return 3 * i1 - 2 + int((i2-1)/2)


def roll16():
   res = __throw_dice__()
   if res > 16:
      res = roll16()
   return res

v = [roll16() for _ in range(1_000_000)]

print(sorted(Counter(v).items()))
```